# Codenameone WebBrowser component hiding tabs when tab titles are left aligned

Tags: tabs, size, codenameone

When I have a Tabs component with the tabs on the left of the screen and one of the tabs contains a WebBrowser component (inside a container with BorderLayout) the tab tile (and icon) is hidden on the tab after the one that contains the WebBrowser component.

This is seen in the Simulator and Android builds - IOS builds are fine.

Basically the WebBrowser is too wide and covers the tabs.

Code sample:

```
Form f = new Form();

f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
tabs.setTabPlacement(Component.LEFT);

f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, tabs);

tabs.addTab("Tab 1", new Label("Label for tab 1"));

WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.setPage("<h1>Web Browse Tab 2", null);

tabs.addTab("Tab 2", wb);
tabs.addTab("Tab 3", new Label("Label for tab 2"));

f.show();
```

[Tab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpoGq.png)
[Tab 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ1BR.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your webbrowser in a BorderLayout container before placing it in a tab.

Also, tab expects **containers** to be added and not **Labels** or any **other component**.

You can simply do it this way:

```
    Form f = new Form(new BorderLayout());
    Tabs tab = new Tabs(Component.LEFT);
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, tab);
    tab.addTab("Tab 1", encloseIn(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS), new Label("Label for tab 1")));
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.setPage("<h1>Web Browse Tab 2", null);
    tab.addTab("Tab 2", BorderLayout.center(wb));
    tab.addTab("Tab 3", encloseIn(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS), new Label("Label for tab 2")));
```

Comment: No good! Have tried to wrap the WebBrowser in a Container with a BorderLayout and still have same issue.

Comment: Did you add the Labels too in containers before adding them to tabs?

Comment: `wb.setPage("<h1>Web Browse Tab 2", null);` is missing closing tag `</h1>` for `<h1>`. could it be that?

Comment: Just checked and still no good. The code above is just a simple example of the issue I'm seeing in the app I've written that loads well formed HTML from a web based system.

Comment: I will suggest you post your complete code (replace sensitive info) and I can help you find the problem

Comment: If you can get the code above to work I'll be happy with that - the example provided exhibits the same issue as I'm seeing so fixing that will be enough.

Comment: What I found out is that BrowserComponent is a peercomponent and it was designed to fit on the screen width, this to me seems like a bug. You can open an issue for that on https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new

Comment: I found another post, before you file an issue please read this https://www.codenameone.com/discussion-forum.html?place=msg%2Fcodenameone-discussions%2F_8MnSQnouSo%2Fhcott_66Z9IJ

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place the `BrowserComponent` in a Tab directly and the Tabs themselves are in the CENTER of the form so this should "just work".

You seem to have done that fine so I'm not sure why this is happening. Make sure you didn't define a theme constant like `tabsOnTopBool`.

If this isn't there then it might be an issue with the internal `TabsLayout` class not leaving enough room for the side tabs.

Comment: Hi Shai, unless the constant is defined by default then it is not set. The effect is only seen with the tab after WebBrowser and it looks like the WebBrowser is full screen width (not just the width of the Tabs 'view') and overflowing to the right over the tab titles. This is not a show stopper for me I will just keep the tab titles on top. Would love to see this fixed at some point.

Comment: Looking a bit at the code and if iOS is fine then I'm guessing this is a `BrowserComponent` issue. Probably a problem with X position with that specific component although its odd this issue will happen both on desktop and Android in the same way. Please file an issue in github with the code and ideally link here http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/